# Delete sub-document from Array using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am new to Mongoose, I have a members schema nested inside room schema as follows:

```
    const MemberSchema = new Schema({
       nickname: String,
       id : String
    });

    const RoomSchema = new Schema({
       code: String,
       members: [MemberSchema]
    });
```

I need to delete only one record from the members array, I have tried this but failed:

```
      Room.findOne({'members.id' : socket.id}).then(result=>{
         result.members.pull({'id' : socket.id});
         result.save();
      })
```

PS: I don't want to use Mongodb default _id, I need it to be the id I gave it before, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just figured out a solution using Filter method, that seems to work pretty well :

```
    //Delete user from Database
    Room.findOne({'members.id' : socket.id}).then(result=>{
      let tempArr = result.members.filter(record=>{
        return record.id === socket.id;
      })
      tempArr[0].remove();
      result.save();
    })
```